# Extending all controller classes from my custom controller class in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2.4

Like in Codeigniter we do have '**core**' folder where we can define our **own controller** like 'MY_Controller' and can be used to extend all the class to extend from this controller is there any possibility to do so in Symfony2.

In symfony I want to create class 'MY_Controller' which extends from the base class 'Controller', and I want all the classes in the controllers to **extend** from MY_Controller' class.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

*Note:*
When working with Symfony2 it is ***strongly*** recommended you follow the Symfony2 coding style. It's basically the same as [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org), with one or two deviations. So underscores are a no-no in class names. Other than that: Symfony is pretty easy to work with, and fully OO, so changing the class a controller extends from is as simple as replacing `extends Controller` with `extends AnotherClass`.
But now, the symfony2-way of using a custom controller:

What you could do, is create a `Core` bundle (CoreBundle henceforth). Then, in this CoreBundle, define a controller, that extends from the Symfony `Controller` component. From the command line, in your project root, use this command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=YourNameSpace/CoreBundle --bundle-name=YourNameSpaceCoreBundle
```

More options [can be found here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html)
After that, you'll find a `DefaultController` class in the bundle directories. (probably in the folder `src/YourNamespace/CoreBundle/Controller`). Then, set about generating your Core controller:

```
php app/console generate:controller --controller=YourNameSpaceCoreBundle:Core
```

See [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html) for more options on how to generate your core controller.

After you've finished setting up your custom controller, you can use it in any of the other bundles at will:

```
namespace YourNameSpace\AnotherBundle\Controller;

use YourNameSpace\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController;

class DefaultController extends CoreController
{//extends from your custom controller
}
```

And that's it: you're done.

Answer (score 0):

- First, don't name the class using underscores as in PSR-0 each underscore char is converted to a directory separator, when used in class name.
- Second, put your controllers to `<bundledir>/Controller/`
- Third, name your controller something like BaseController and extend all other controllers from it.
- Fourth, think of using dependency injection rather than coupling functionality in a base controller.

Comment: Second point: just use the Symfony2 `generate:*` commands, controllers will be put in the directories they belong. Third point: That's what the OP is asking: how to do that. fourth point: his own controller will extend from the Symfony2 `Controller` component. Don't advise him to set about reinventing the wheel: the controller will have access to the container object

Comment: Well, yes, it is possible to use `generate:*`, but personally, I found it slower, then creating a file myself in my IDE... This feature is mainly for newbies, I guess.

Comment: Perhaps, but then you don't know if the core controller of the OP is going to require some core services, resources and other objects. Setting up an entire bundle mannually isn't as quick as generating one using the `generate:bundle` command, though

Comment: Hm... I didn't get from the question that the questioner doesn't have a bundle. If it's the point, then for sure, generating a bundle is much easier using the `generate:bundle`. The question was strictly about extending controllers, not about how to create a bundle ;) But who knows, maybe you guessed the root of the problem ;)

Comment: It's not about him having a bundle or not. If he wants all of his controllers to extend from a custom base controller, then that custom base controller should be treated as an _abstract_ component, and thus does not belong in a bundle that does actual work. That's why, in my answer, I advise the OP to generate a Core bundle, put everything in there, and extend those core objects in the actual working bundles

Comment: I see your point. However, you think a bit too global, I believe. It can be a relatively small bundle who's controllers may have some common functionality that's just may make no sense to move to the separate core bundle. Anyway, without knowing the details, we can only guess and predict. Your approach may be possible as well, depending on the project size and amount of components.

Comment: I'm just looking at this as a rather broad question, so I suggested what I consider to be _"best practice"_ in cases like these. Next to dependency injection, separation of concern is a principle that applies on all fronts: each unit (be it a method, class, block, or bundle) should have a distinct purpose. A Core bundle is, in that respect, far from _"too global"_, it's common sense, and it helps to organize the project itself.